# how to use websocket to send messages proactively?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket

In websocket, `@OnOpen` indicate do something when it connect; `@OnMessage` indicate do something when it send the message to you;  `@OnClose` indicate do something when it tell you that it will disconnect; `@OnError` indicate do something when it has error!but now I want to send messages proactively rather than waiting for the client's message. How should I do?

Comment: Sending a message (or request) is always proactive. If it's not proactive, it is called 'returning a response' in common terminology.

Comment: It's a websocket. Send a message. You don't need a callback to do things proactively.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster,@Mad Physicist, I know ! but how should I code?

Comment: Your websocket implementation should offer a `Write()` or `Send()` method to send a message. You can call this from any thread in your app once the websocket is opened (there is no requirement to call it exclusively from an event handler).

Comment: Sending proactively: when should the message be sent? When the application starts? When the user clicks a button? When some timestamp is reached?